# Triple Boot Bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, 17.04, mint

Im gonna triple boot windows 10 Linux MInt and Ubuntu 17.04
I've already installed LInux MInt and for bootloader I put /dev/sda but when im installing ubuntu what should i put bootloader as?

Comment: do you mean boot loader location?? /dev/sda is a HDD not a boot loader. Use the same location,

Comment: im a noob xd ty

Comment: Are you using UEFI or BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Mint uses grub as a bootloader; the same as Ubuntu does. So your bootloader is already installed.
You can reinstall grub when installing Ubuntu, use /dev/sda again.
Or install Ubuntu without installing grub.
Then boot into Mint and `sudo update-grub` to add ubuntu to the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be

1. Uninstall GRUB from Linuxmint
2. Uninstall GRUB from Ubuntu
3. Install rEFInd from either Ubuntu or Linuxmint
4. profit!